# Puppet template erb if variable is not defined keep default

Tags: puppet, ruby

I am trying to learn puppet and I can not understand how I can setup template erb to choose default value if variable is not defined in common.yaml or in node.yaml. This is what I have tried:
1)

```
# we don't need to run the embedded HTTP server here
<% if @elasticsearch_http_enabled %>
elasticsearch_http_enabled = <%= @elasticsearch_http_enabled %>
<% else %>
#elasticsearch_http_enabled = false
<% end %>
```

2)

```
# we don't need to run the embedded HTTP server here
<%- if @elasticsearch_http_enabled then -%>
elasticsearch_http_enabled = <%= @elasticsearch_http_enabled %>
<% else %>
#elasticsearch_http_enabled = false
<% end %>
```

3)

```
# we don't need to run the embedded HTTP server here
<% if @elasticsearch_http_enabled then %>
elasticsearch_http_enabled = <%= @elasticsearch_http_enabled %>
<% else %>
#elasticsearch_http_enabled = false
<% end %>
```

When I tried these I got error:

> Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on
>   SERVER: Could not find data item gl2_srv_elasticsearch_http_enabled in
>   any Hiera data file and no default supplied at
>   /etc/puppet/envs/testing/modules/graylog2/manifests/server.pp:28 on
>   node

How can I make it so if I do not define the variable it puts the default variable to the config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template is not generating this error. Instead, your manifest is retrieving the data with a call like this:

```
hiera('gl2_srv_elasticsearch_http_enabled')
```

This will fail if in your Hiera data (let's assume YAML), this key does not appear, e.g.

```
gl2_srv_elasticsearch_http_enabled: true
```

To avoid this problem, define a default and pass it as the second argument to the `hiera` function.

```
hiera('gl2_srv_elasticsearch_http_enabled', false)
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the above.

Instead, [supply defaults for all of your parameters](http://garylarizza.com/blog/2013/12/08/when-to-hiera/) in, e.g. a `manifests/params.pp`.

An example `init.pp`:

```
class elasticsearch (
    $http_enabled        = $::elasticsearch:params:http_enabled,
) inherits ::elasticsearch:params {
    # your class here
}
```

An example `params.pp`:

```
class elasticsearch:params {
    $http_enabled = false 
}
```

This lets you isolate code which must choose different defaults for, e.g. different operating systems or distributions.

If you're 100% sure the default should always be false, you can just declare it as such in `init.pp` and forget about adding it to `params.pp`.

```
class elasticsearch (
    $http_enabled        = false,
) inherits ::elasticsearch:params {
    # your class here
}
```

Your template is then simplified to:

```
elasticsearch_http_enabled = <%= @http_enabled %>
```

Comment: Hello!
How can I do it without params and without defining it anywhere so if its not defined then it just takes the variable that is commented out. I hope you understood what I ment.

Comment: That's probably not a good idea, because if elasticsearch changes _their_ idea of the default, then you will get unexpected behavior.

Comment: Oh that would be the issue as well yes. I guess I will keep it the way you sed :) Thank you :)

Comment: Fair point, but does not address the issue from the question.